# Buffering in QGIS3 is returning giant circles

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, buffer

I'm trying to buffer some lines in QGIS. However, the result I'm returning are giant circles. I've tried several different CRS and made sure the project and layer had the same CRS but the result is still the same. The CRS is also not decimal but meters. Not sure what I'm missing.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You almost certainly "changed" the projection rather than reprojected your data

Comment: How did you project your layer? Via save as or via set crs? Use save as ;)

Comment: I've tried that. I right click on the layer and go to Export>Save Feature As then set format as geojson and crs to EPSG:2231,  Geometry trype = automatic. When I go back to buffer the points I still get large circles.

Comment: First set the layers crs back to its original. Then use save as to reproject it. Not sure how QGIS handles geojson specifications, so I would try another format to make sure thats not the error source. Also whats "giant"? Does it cover a whole continent or the entire world...?

Comment: So I think the geojson was the problem. It worked when I saved it as a .shp . Thanks a ton.